# Spring Data Neo4J - NotInTransactionException while modifying set of nodeEntity

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

We are using spring-data-neo4j with repository methods and annotated queries. Formerly, we used SDN with a rest connection to a standalone server. Performance was very poor, though, so we decided to use SDN with an embedded neo4j instance. But that does not work as expected.

Here are some classes

The node entity

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedToVia;

import com.xxx.xyz.relationships.UserToAnnotation;
import com.xxx.xyz.relationships.UserToBookmark;
import com.xxx.xyz.relationships.UserToGroup;
import com.xxx.xyz.relationships.UserToLastReadMedia;
import com.xxx.xyz.relationships.UserToLicenseOwner;
import com.xxx.xyz.relationships.UserToLicenseReader;
import com.xxx.xyz.relationships.UserToUser;

/** Simple user class. */
@NodeEntity
public class Neo4jUser {

    @GraphId
    Long id;

    private String type;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Indexed
    private String nickname;

    private String passwordHash;

    private String givenName;

    private String familyName;

    private Long birthdate;


    @JsonIgnore
    @RelatedToVia(type = "isIn", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<UserToGroup> memberships;

    public Neo4jUser() {
    }

    //constructor

    //getter / setter


    public void isIn(final Neo4jGroup group, final String role) {
        memberships.add(new UserToGroup(this, group, role));
    }



}
```

One relationship entity

```
package com.xxx.xyz.relationships;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.EndNode;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.StartNode;

import com.xxx.xyz.model.db.Neo4jGroup;
import com.xxx.xyz.model.db.Neo4jUser;

@RelationshipEntity(type="isIn")
public class UserToGroup {

    @GraphId
    Long id;

    @Fetch @StartNode
    private Neo4jUser user;

    @Fetch @EndNode
    private Neo4jGroup group;

    private String role;

    public UserToGroup(){
    }

    public UserToGroup(final Neo4jUser user, final Neo4jGroup group, final String role)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.group = group;
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

The user repository

```
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<Neo4jUser> {

//annotated cypher queries

}
```

spring applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.xyz.service" />

    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/graph.db" />

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.xxx.xyz.repository" />


</beans>
```

maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

When trying to modify the set `memberships` by using the method `Neo4JUser.isIn()` the following exception is thrown

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getResource(PersistenceManager.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.relationshipCreate(PersistenceManager.java:161)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.createRelationship(NodeManager.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.createRelationshipTo(NodeImpl.java:578)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.createRelationshipTo(NodeProxy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.DelegatingGraphDatabase.createRelationship(DelegatingGraphDatabase.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityStateHandler.getOrCreateRelationship(EntityStateHandler.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityStateHandler.useOrCreateState(EntityStateHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.write(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessor.persistEntities(RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessor.setValue(RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.updateValue(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.update(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.add(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:108)
    at com.xxx.xyz.model.db.Neo4jUser.isIn(Neo4jUser.java:187)
```

As I found out doing some research, the rest connection of SDN does not use transactions, the embedded version does, so `NotInTransactionException` are possible.

Moreover, we didn't expect `save()` to be triggered, when manipulating a set with relationships. We always called save() manually after. Why is that?

But what is done wrong here?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is indeed a bit confusing and I have had  the same problems. If you are using the sets for relationships in you model, the set will be backed by SDN. So if you make any modifications to the set, SDN will try to change your DB accoringly(ie. creating/deleting relationships).
If you dont want your model to be backed by the database you should use Iterable.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#reference:programming_model:relationships:relatedto

Comment: Thank you for the information. How can I avoid the exception, what needs to be changed / configured? How did you solve the problem?

Comment: As I mentioned, the easiest way is to use Iterable in your model classes. Then you cant create/delete relationships unintentionally. If however you want to be able to create/delete relationships directly with your model classes, you need to make sure that it happens in a transaction(use @Transactional).

Comment: For @Tranactional you should also add this to your spring config: <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>.

Comment: Let's say we stick to Sets, where would I place the @Transactional annotation to make the method isIn() exception-safe?

Comment: It depends on how long you want you transaction to last :) At the very least, you will need it on the method where you are manipulating the set. Also note, that @Transactional per default only works on public methods and only when they are called from an outside class( see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html  Section 12.5.6 )

Comment: Finally we managed to solve our issue, because following your advice, we still had problems. That's why the reply is so late. We made some mistakes concerning autowiring, but now we got it running. Performance increase is tremendous compared to REST communication. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AndyB Getting a 404 on that link.