# NotInTransactionException when adding to mapped set

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-transactions, spring-data-neo4j

I have two `@NodeEntities` mapped via SDN using simple mapping, `PersonNode` and `FamilyNode`. `FamilyNode` has a `@RelatedTo` collection, children.  I also have a `FamilyService` (using Spring's `@Service` annotation) with `@Transactional` annotation on an `updateFamily` method.  This method loads the `FamilyNode` given an id, and uses a callback interface to modify the node.  In one implementation of the callback, I am adding a `PersonNode` to the children collection, and this is generating the `NotInTransactionException`, specifically at the point that Neo4J is attempting to create the relationship between the `FamilyNode` and the `PersonNode`.

Source code can be found at [github](https://github.com/jbonevich/ancestral/blob/master/ancestral/) and in particular a [failing test](https://github.com/jbonevich/ancestral/blob/master/ancestral/src/test/java/com/bonevich/ancestral/family/FamilyServiceTest.java).  Here are relevant bits of the code:

FamilyNode.java:

```
 @NodeEntity
 public class FamilyNode implements Family {

    @Indexed(indexName = "families", unique = true)
    private String id;
    @GraphId
    private Long identifier;
    @RelatedTo(elementClass = PersonNode.class, type = "CHILD")
    private Set<Person> children;

    void addChild(Person child) {
        if (this.children == null) {
        this.children = new HashSet<>();
        }
        this.children.add(child);
    }
}
```

PersonNode.java:

```
@NodeEntity
public class PersonNode implements Person {

    @RelatedTo(elementClass = FamilyNode.class, type = "CHILD", direction = INCOMING)
    private Family childOf;
    @Indexed(indexName = "people", unique = true)
    private String id;
    @GraphId
    private Long identifier;
}
```

FamilyRepository.java:

```
public interface FamilyRepository extends GraphRepository<Family> {
    public FamilyNode findById(String id);
}
```

FamilyServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service
public class FamilyServiceImpl implements FamilyService {

    @Autowired
    private FamilyRepository families;
    @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate template;

    @Override
    public List<Family> getFamilies(String[] ids) {
        List<Family> families = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String id : ids) {
            families.add(getFamily(id));
        }
        return families;
    }

    @Override
    public Family getFamily(String id) {
        return familyNode(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Family createFamily(Family family) {
        return lazyLoadRelationships((FamilyNode) this.families.save(family));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Family updateFamily(String id, FamilyNodeUpdater updater) {
        return this.families.save(updater.update(familyNode(id)));
    }

    private FamilyNode familyNode(String id) {
        return lazyLoadRelationships(this.families.findById(id));
    }

    private FamilyNode lazyLoadRelationships(FamilyNode family) {
        this.template.fetch(family.getFather());
        this.template.fetch(family.getMother());
        this.template.fetch(family.getChildren());
        return family;
    }

}
```

and the failing test, FamilyServiceTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { TestConfig.class })
public class FamilyServiceTest {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { com.bonevich.ancestral.family.FamilyServiceImpl.class }, resourcePattern = "FamilyServiceImpl.class")
    @EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackageClasses = { com.bonevich.ancestral.family.FamilyNode.class })
    static class TestConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
            return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("/data/neo4j/ancestral-familyservicetest/")
                    .newGraphDatabase();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private FamilyService families;

    @Autowired
    private GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService;

    @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testUpdateFamily() {
        this.families.createFamily(FamilyNode.instance("testFamily"));

        Transaction tx = this.graphDatabaseService.beginTx();
        PersonNode person = PersonNode.instance("John", "Johanson", "M", "a_person");
        PersonNode expectedChild = this.neo4jTemplate.save(person);
        final long childId = expectedChild.getIdentifier();
        tx.success();
        tx.finish();

        Family actualFamily = this.families.updateFamily("testFamily", new FamilyNodeUpdater() {
            @Override
            public FamilyNode update(FamilyNode family) {
                family.addChild(FamilyServiceTest.this.neo4jTemplate.findOne(childId, PersonNode.class));
                return family;
            }
        });

        assertThat(actualFamily.getId(), is("testFamily"));
        assertThat(actualFamily.getChildren().get(0), is((Person) expectedChild));
    }

}
```

Running this test yields the following exception stack:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NoTransactionState.acquireWriteLock(NoTransactionState.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.LockType$2.acquire(LockType.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getNodeForProxy(NodeManager.java:473)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$6.lookup(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:733)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.createRelationshipTo(NodeProxy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.obtainSingleRelationship(RelationshipHelper.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.createSingleRelationship(RelationshipHelper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.createAddedRelationships(RelationshipHelper.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToFieldAccessor.createAddedRelationships(RelatedToFieldAccessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessor.setValue(RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.updateValue(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.update(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.add(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:126)
    at com.bonevich.ancestral.family.FamilyNode.addChild(FamilyNode.java:124)
    at com.bonevich.ancestral.family.FamilyServiceTest$1.update(FamilyServiceTest.java:64)
    at com.bonevich.ancestral.family.FamilyServiceImpl.updateFamily(FamilyServiceImpl.java:42)
    at com.bonevich.ancestral.family.FamilyServiceTest.testUpdateFamily(FamilyServiceTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I have got to believe I am missing something in configuring SDN or Transactions, but have been unable to track it down.

Comment: Being new to StackOverflow, could someone explain the vote down?

Comment: In your entity I'd go for `@RelatedTo(elementClass = PersonNode.class, type = "CHILD")
    private Set<Person> children = new Hashset<>();` and remove the null check from addChild()

Comment: This did not resolve the issue either.

Comment: It was merely a suggestion and not intended as fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently answered this question here:
[Spring Data Neo4J - NotInTransactionException while modifying set of nodeEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871635/spring-data-neo4j-notintransactionexception-while-modifying-set-of-nodeentity/18872206#18872206)

In short, it has to do with the fact that these List are special list which are backed by SDN and any modification is immediately persisted to the DB. If you want to prevent this behaviour, you should use Iterable in your model classes. If you have some more question after reading the link, just post them as a comment.

Comment: Yes, I saw that question.  I do want this behavior - a relationship between a family and a child needs to be created. So a Set is called for.  The other question you responded to I do not consider having been answered.  @AndyB (the original questioner) just noted that he had resolved his issue, but gave no actual specifics on what the solution was (just something about fixing autowiring).

Comment: Oh, and I am too much a newb to comment on that question.  I tried to post a question as an "answer" but a moderator removed it (undoubtedly correctly so; but still I had no recourse, so I posted this question).

Comment: Well, in that case you just have to put the modification of the Set into a transaction. Either manually by extending the transaction(notice that `                 family.addChild(FamilyServiceTest.this.neo4jTemplate.findOne(childId, PersonNode.class));` is running outside of an transaction) or by doing the modification inside of a method annotated with @Transactional.

Comment: So for your test case moving the ` tx.success();
        tx.finish();` right before the asserts should solve the problem

Comment: The transaction within the test is just to persist a Person.  The test runs updateFamily() which is a service call using @Transactional.  The latter is what is failing.

Comment: I think you dont have transactionmanagment configured. Im not very familiar with the java based config, but you might want to try this:
@EnableTransactionManagement (http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/10/spring-3-1-m2-configuration-enhancements/)